# How to tell if rows were entered by a file vs. data entry?

Tags: soql

(Warning:  SQL expert, Salesforce.com N00b)

Just by looking at the data, is there a way to tell whether rows were entered by a file import (and if so if you can get to any file properties), vs. data entry?

Thanks in advance.
Jim

Comment: When you say entered by a file import do you mean via the Apex Data Loader?

Comment: Only if you use a Specific user for API / data integrations. Otherwise no there is not

Comment: >do you mean via the Apex Data Loader? 
Don't know at the moment, as the guy that is doing file imports is out of town for the week.   
 
>Only if you use a Specific user for API / data integrations
Not the case, as same user does other activities.    
 
>If you see a large number of records where the date/time created
Thought so.  Was hoping to avoid going down this road, but this is likely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see a large number of records where the date/time created is exactly the same or very close, you can be fairly confident that data entry (or possibly some batch process) created them.

If you want to be able to know for sure, you can do as Eric suggests in the comments and have a user account that you use only for data loader/API operations.

I have another way to do that that has additional benefits.  For some objects, I have a field called "BatchKey".  In it, I put a value that's unique to that object and the set of data being uploaded (usually user initials and date).  I use it so that I can undo all of a batch of uploads.  A non-blank value in "BatchKey" indicates that the record was uploaded.  A blank value indicates data entry.

Both of these methods call for diligence in using the special user account or in remembering to fill in the field properly.